# jquery: how to animate the moveup?

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a list of DIVs arranged vertically, I already use .fadeOut() to delete one of the DIV in the middle, but I don't know how to generate the slowly moveup effect for the DIVs below the deleted one.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get both the fadeout and the slide up, you can use the excellent "animate" call:

```
$("#mydiv").animate({ opacity: "0", height: "0" });
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this..

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
 $('#div').slideUp('slow', function() {
// Animation complete.
});});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/TSQAW/)

for more reference read this..[slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $("<div>").appendTo(document.body);
}
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).hide(2000, function () {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)